# Check if date('l') is in an Array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, date

I want to check if a date value is in an array.
This is what I did:

```
$day = array('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday');
if(date('l') === $day){
   //Do your thing
}
```

I guess I'm missing something or not fully understand why this doesn't work.
The idea is to make this statement `false` if the date is past Thuesday until Sunday. This was the only way I could think of because this is allready in a loop.

Comment: `if (in_array($date('l), $day)) {...}`

Answer (score 2):

[`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.in-array.php) does exactly what you want:

```
<?php
$day = array('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday');
if(in_array(date('l'), $day)){
  //Do your thing
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try this to find a variable is array or not

```
$day = array('Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday');

echo is_array($day) ? 'Array' : 'not an Array';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.in-array.php) function, like this:

```
if( in_array( date('l'), $day ) ) { 
     // the day from date('l') is in array!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

date('N') will return a numerical representation of th day of the week, being 4 a thursday. So you want do stuff if date('N') is less than 4. Hence:

```
if (date('N') < 4) {
   do_your_thing
}
```